# Writing to MySQL with Python without using SQL strings

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I am importing data into my Python3 environment and then writing it to a MySQL database. However, there is a lot of different data tables, and so writing out each INSERT statement isn't really pragmatic, plus some have 50+ columns.

Is there a good way to create a table in MySQL directly from a dataframe, and then send insert commands to that same table using a dataframe of the same format, without having to actually type out all the col names? I started trying to call column names and format it and concat everything as a string, but it is extremely messy.

Ideally there is a function out there to directly handle this. For example:

```
apiconn.request("GET", url, headers=datheaders)

#pull in some JSON data from an API
eventres = apiconn.getresponse()
eventjson = json.loads(eventres.read().decode("utf-8"))

#create a dataframe from the data
eventtable = json_normalize(eventjson)


dbconn = pymysql.connect(host='hostval',
user='userval',
passwd='passval',
db='dbval')
cursor = dbconn.cursor()

sql = sqltranslate(table = 'eventtable', fun = 'append') 
#where sqlwrite() is some magic function that takes a dataframe and 
#creates SQL commands that pymysql can execute.

cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a way to abstract the generation of the SQL statements.

A library like [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) will do a good job, including a powerful way to construct DDL, DML, and DQL statements without needing to directly write any SQL.